# Retrieve Office 365 directory information from SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I was wondering if is it possible to retrieve Office 365 directory information (i.e. security group membership) from SharePoint online programmatically (for example through a workflow custom action)? 
By the way, I am not looking for retrieving Sharepoint group membership information.

I know the custom development is pretty limited with SharePoint online since the code has to run as a sandbox solution. Is there any web service or any another solution available?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for information about this matter but I could not find anything so I guess there is no way to do this.

In our case there is an active directory synchronized with office 365. So we will use a powershell script to read data from AD and update a sharepoint list every day.
Then we will be able to use this data from custom code (like a workflow custom action).